# Session time out issue in case of tomcat realm form based authentication

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat

I am using **form based authentication** of Tomcat (7.0.34) realm. My problem is described below.

I have *signA.jsp* which is a protected page. Then I have *auth.jsp* which is the login page.

1st request to application goes to *signA.jsp*, then the request is redirected to *auth.jsp* (as at this moment, user is not authenticated) where the user can enter login credentials and hit submit. Tomcat gets the action as j_security_check.Once authenticated successfully and if there is no error, the request goes back to *signA.jsp* which forwards the request to application home page *home.jsp*. This works perfectly fine.

If authetication fails, the request goes to *errorA.jsp* file which re-directs the request to *signA.jsp* along with statusId as get parameter and further the request is re-directed again to *auth.jsp*.

Now, let's say I am logged in to application and session times out when I am on page *C.jsp*, and then when I click to navigate to other page of application, the request is re-directed to *auth.jsp* which is fine actually. But again when try to re-login, I have found that the request goes to the last accessed page in the previous logged in session, and in this case it is *C.jsp*. Ideally I would have liked the request to go through the first default page after login which is *home.jsp* where I keep the login details and other details in session which are used across the application.

Any idea what could be the problem? Appreciated if you can provide me the solution to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Digging for hours, came up with some hacky solution.

In your session object(by calling .isNew() etc), you cannot tell if there was a timeout or not, because if there was a timeout, tomcat realm will already create a new session. So you need to set an attribute in your session when you successfully login.

Add a filter on your protected url. Don't forget to add it to web.xml.
Let's say your Login Servlet is under `/protected/login` and all other requests will go `/protected/some_other_url`

If a request is coming to `/protected/some_other_url` with your attribute null, it means there was a timeout.

You can omit the `path.startsWith` check if your url pattern for filter is right or login servlet may be under different prefix etc.. you got the idea.

```
public class TimeoutFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        String path = request.getServletPath();

        // login after timeout occurred
        if (session != null && session.getAttribute(YOUR_ATTRIBUTE) == null && path.startsWith("/protected") && !path.equals("/protected/login")) {
            response.sendRedirect("/protected/YOUR_START_PAGE");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @acheron55 for your response. I was not able to redirect the request to login page from filter. On session time out, I would have liked to re-direct incoming all the ajax requests as well to login page.

Comment: Tomcat realm should just redirect you to login after timeout, not filter. After login, you would normally be redirected to your old request, but filter will handle that and will redirect you to your start page. I edited response.sendRedirect("/protected/login"); this code